# Как передать состояние компонента в redux storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

у меня есть форма которая должна добавлять комментарии,но т.к. я только начал учить редакс ,я не понимаю как данные формы которые я передаю в состояние компонента передать в мой сервис(В массив comments) через редакс

My service component

```
export default class ArticlestoreServices {
  data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "most popular language in 2019",
      description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam harum distinctio necessitatibus eius voluptates. Voluptatem, excepturi necessitatibus. Recusandae fugiat sequi necessitatibus veritatis, hic vero molestias iure? Possimus iusto soluta facere a, nesciunt sunt reprehenderit et repellat odio. Libero, eveniet exercitationem. Nostrum quis odit unde nihil, delectus soluta aut, deserunt qui quia neque, laboriosam aliquid maxime id. Magnam, ipsa officia eum commodi molestiae iure ea natus praesentium eligendi, explicabo totam quis, voluptatem impedit itaque excepturi error est tempora magni eaque corrupti at voluptatibus? Atque autem dolorem laboriosam error alias necessitatibus omnis iste, nulla aliquam dolores mollitia optio aperiam sit delectus deleniti.",
      author: "John",
      comments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John",
          desc:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Commodi, beatae!"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Kein",
          desc:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, ducimus?"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "angularVSvue",
      description:
        "AAAALorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae eius veritatis quod iste ducimus suscipit nostrum aut alias dicta placeat rem doloribus consectetur modi fugit, dolor praesentium quidem tempore sint eveniet minima eum quasi vitae est dolores. Incidunt, maxime a commodi placeat necessitatibus nemo fuga excepturi reprehenderit culpa libero in sapiente itaque tempore explicabo quo ab? Soluta, debitis fuga necessitatibus numquam dolore officia vero praesentium nulla ducimus labore. Nihil fuga natus cum hic ad totam laudantium omnis, enim veniam ducimus nobis accusantium cupiditate earum eum, eveniet possimus amet. Voluptas culpa deleniti necessitatibus nesciunt placeat itaque perferendis consequatur, eos quam enim.",
      author: "Steve",
      comments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Daniel",
          desc:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nisi, cum!"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Monro",
          desc:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, tempora."
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  getArticles() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

My Article Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withArticlestoreService } from "../hoc";

class ArticlePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { article: [], author: "", comment: "" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { articlestoreService } = this.props;
    const data = articlestoreService.getArticles();

    const currentArticle = data.find(
      article => article.id === +this.props.match.params.id
    );

    this.setState({
      article: currentArticle
    });
  }
  onChangeHandlerName(e) {
    this.setState({
      author: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onChangeHandlerComment(e) {
    this.setState({
      comment: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    const { title, description, author, comments } = this.state.article;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> title:{title}</h1>
        <h2>{description}</h2>
        <h3>author:{author}</h3>
        <hr />
        <div className="comments">
          <ul>
            {comments !== undefined
              ? comments.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <li className="commentary" key={item.id}>
                      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                      <h2>{item.desc}</h2>
                    </li>
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </ul>
          <form action="submit" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="name"
              onChange={this.onChangeHandlerName.bind(this)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="commentary..."
              onChange={this.onChangeHandlerComment.bind(this)}
            />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ articles }) => {
  return { articles };
};

export default withArticlestoreService()(connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticlePage));
```

my reducer

```
const initialState = {
  articles: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ARTICLES_LOADED":
      return {
        articles: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Если уж совсем переделал извини, первый раз самый важен ^^

    //reducer
    const initialState = {
      articles: []
    };

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "ARTICLES_LOADED":
           state = {
            ...state,
            articles: {  
                ...action.payload
               }
           }
           break;
        default: 
            state = {
                ...state
            }

        return state;
    }

    const store =  createStore(reducer, initialState);
    export default store;


    // компонент который вернет сразу все заголовки
    import store from 'store';

    class ArticlePage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.store = store;
        this.store.subscribe( () => this.setState({}) );
      }
      onSubmit( i ){
        /*
            сделал через клик, а не через отправку форму. 
            Лично мне так проще, ибо тут я уверен про то, как передаются данные, и как я их достать могу.
        */
        let arr = this.store.getState().articles;
        arr[i].comments.push({ name: this.refs.name.value, desc: this.refs.comment.value });
        this.store.dispatch({ type:'ARTICLES_LOADED', payload: arr });
      }
      render(){
        return(
            <div>
            {this.store.getState().articles.map(( article, i) => {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
                        <h2>{article.description}</h2>
                        <h3>{article.author}</h3>
                        {article.comments.map((comment, j) => {
                            return(
                                <div> {comment.name} say {comment.desc} </div> 
                            )
                        })
                         <div>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="name"
                              ref="name"
                            />
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="commentary..."
                              ref='comment'
                            />
                            <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this,i)}/>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}

            </div>
        )
      }
```